# Replace object from a file into the main.json along with wildcards using jq 1.5

Tags: json, jq

I have been able to add a json object - that is saved in a file named auth.json - into the Main.json file.
Auth.json

```
{ 
    "name": "Authorization",
    "description": "this is authorization",
     "in": "header",
}
```

Main.json

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
    "paths": {
    "/agents/delta": {
      "get": {
        "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "since",
            "in": "query",
          }
        ]
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

Using the below command, I have been able to add it in the below path `.paths.<any method that starts with />.get.parameters`. Also it is getting added only if the parameters array does not already contain the 'Authorization' object.
Working command:

```
jq --slurpfile auth auth.json ' .paths |= with_entries(  if (.key|startswith("/")) and (.value.get.parameters[].name != "Authorization") then  .value.get.parameters += $auth  else  . end )' test.json > test1.json
```

But now I have to added it under every object within the  `.paths.<any method that starts with />.<any value>.parameters`.

So for a input json like below.

```
{
      "swagger": "2.0",
        "paths": {
        "/agents/delta": {
          "get": {
            "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "since",
                "in": "query",
              }
            ]
            }
            "put": {
                        "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "since",
                "in": "query",
              }
            ]
            }
            }
            }
            }
```

expected output should be like:

```
{
      "swagger": "2.0",
        "paths": {
        "/agents/delta": {
          "get": {
            "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "since",
                "in": "query",
              },
              { 
                "name": "Authorization",
                "description": "this is authorization",
                "in": "header",
              }
            ]
            }
            "put": {
                        "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "since",
                "in": "query",
              },
              { 
                "name": "Authorization",
                "description": "this is authorization",
                "in": "header",
              }
            ]
            }
            }
            }
            }
```

So I tried the below command.

```
jq --slurpfile auth auth.json ' .paths |= with_entries(  if (.key|startswith("/")) and (.value | .. | .parameters[]?.name != "Authorization") then  .value| .. |.parameters? += $auth  else  . end )' test.json
```

But I get the error

```
jq: error (at test.json:3027): object ({"name":"si...) and array ([{"name":"A...) cannot be added
```

I tried using `inside` like the below

```
jq --slurpfile auth auth.json '.paths |= with_entries(  if (.key|startswith("/")) and (.value | inside (["get","put","post"]) |.parameters[].name != "Authorization") then  .value.get.parameters += $auth  else  . end )' test.json
```

But I get this error:

```
jq: error (at test.json:3027): array (["get","put...) and object ({"get":{"de...) cannot have their containment checked
```

I also have to be able to remove any object with `"name": "Authorization"` if it exists and replace it with the contents of auth.json.

Any leads will be helpful.

So the expected output is as below:

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but it does not help that it does not adhere to the [mcve] guidelines. Notably, the example is not minimal, and you have not shown the expected output for the case in which your program is failing.  Also your requirements are not very clear, especially since your jq program uses `..`.  Maybe it would be helpful if you gave at least two short examples, each showing clearly the input and expected output.

Comment: @peak. Thank you. That helped. I will put in more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are not entirely clear to me, but the following variant of your program does match one interpretation of your description of the problem and illustrates how to use `map_values` and `all/2`:

```
.paths |= with_entries(
  if (.key|startswith("/"))
  then .value |= map_values(
    if has("parameters") and all(.parameters[]; .name != "Authorization")
    then .parameters += $auth
    else . end ) 
  else . end )
```

And here's a program that matches one interpretation of your second set of requirements regarding removal of "Authorization" entries:

```
.paths |= with_entries(
  if (.key|startswith("/"))
  then .value |= map_values(
    if has("parameters")
    then
    # first delete and then add
      .parameters |= map(select( .name != "Authorization"))
      | .parameters += $auth
    else  . end )
  else . end)
```